# Fetch most significant word of a double

Tags: c

I would like to fetch the most significant 32-bit word of a `double` variable.

I know that a `double` is 8 bytes long and I expect as a return of my function an `unsigned long` that will hold the 4 most significant bytes of a double.

```
unsigned long doublesmsw(double value);

int main()
{
  double d=54645654663905 ;
  unsigned long fin=doublesmsw(d);
  printf("%lu", fin );
  return 0;
}

unsigned long doublesmsw(double value)
{
  unsigned long long mask=0x00000000ffffffff ;
  return ((unsigned long long) value>>32 & mask);
}
```

Comment: Try this "solution": `union convert { double d; unsigned char u[sizeof (double)]; }; union convert x; x.d = -42.24; for (int k = 0; k < sizeof (double); k++) printf("%02X ", x.u[k]);`

Answer (score 4):

Typecasting `value` to `unsigned long long` simply truncates it to integer, it does **not** yield the memory representation of the `double` in an `unsigned long long`. Use `memcpy` instead:

```
unsigned long doublesmsw(double value)
{
    unsigned long r;
    memcpy(&r, &value, sizeof(r));
    // or memcpy(&r, (char *)&value + 4, sizeof(r));, depending on endianness
    return r;
}
```

Or, as suggested, if the target architecture uses the same endianness for integers and floating-point numbers (which it almost always does):

```
unsigned long doublesmsw(double value)
{
    unsigned long long r;
    memcpy(&r, &value, sizeof(r));
    return r >> 32;
}
```

Comment: It’s probably better to memcpy to a `uint64_t` and then return that shifted by 32; that way you avoid needing to deal with endianness (unless your machine has a different endianness for floating point data than it does for integer data, which is weird but possible).

Comment: @StephenCanon Right, fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference the same area of memory, not just cast the value. One way to do this following the C99 (or thereabouts) permitted aliasing optimisations is to cast through a union, e.g.

```
union doubleUll {
    double d;
    unsigned long long ull;
};

unsigned long doublesmsw(double value)
{
    union doubleUll u;
    u.d = value;
    return (u.ull >> 32) & mask;
}
```

... however Kerrek is correct, this is actually undefined by C99, but it's fairly common and was one of the recommended ways of casting types avoiding strict aliasing problems in the early 2000s after it was started to be adopted by compilers. See a longer write-up here: [Understanding Strict Aliasing](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html#union_1)

Comment: This is undefined behaviour, non?

Comment: @KerrekSB: C11 footnote 95 (footnote 82 in C99 + TC3): "If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’)."

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
uint32_t msw(double d);
{
    uint32_t n[2];
    memcpy(n, &d, 8);
    return n[0];
}
```

Your milage may vary depending on endianness and other platform specifics.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` and `std::copy` in a C program?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You know, C++ is superior and no C functions should be used, it's bad style even in a C program.

Comment: @H2CO3 While I personally rather program in C++ than C, I wouldn't call it superior. C has its place in world too. And do you mean that the OP should use C++ function in C program even though it wouldn't work? Or force the OP to change language just because you don't like C?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No, I was merely being sarcastic :) There are quite a few programmers around here who actually believe in that one language is superior to another (once I has been badly told off in Lounge<C++> by one of these people), this is comparable to racism...

Comment: @H2CO3 Ah okay, I misunderstood you, sorry about that. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Whoops. Fixed!